# How do I stream to Twitch.tv?

Tags: video-streaming

I am using the latest updated Ubuntu 12.04 and I would like to know how I can stream my second monitor to an RTMP address. (Twitch.tv)

Is there any kind of streaming on Linux I can set up, or an up to date guide that shows how to do it in 12.04?

Comment: I got it working rather easily with OBS: https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/how-to-livestream-from-linux-to-twitch-a-simple-guide-to-being-awesome-on-linux.9257

Answer (score 2):

[**Red5**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/red5-server) [image: Install red5-server]

This is a free RTMP server for recording and streaming to a Flash client. Its features according to the [project's home page](http://www.red5.org/) are:

> - Streaming Audio/Video (FLV and MP3)
> - Recording Client Streams (FLV only)
> - Shared Objects
> - Live Stream Publishing (live h264 supported now)
> - Remoting ( AMF0/ AMF3)

The application is mainly intended to setup your own RTMP server. We have no experience on how to set up sending a stream to a remote streaming server and if we are able to do this for Twitch.tv. Some documentation exists on the project's home page indicating that this can be done.

A (somehow quite nested) documentation can be found on the projects pages:

- [Red5 Getting Started](http://www.red5.org/getting-started/)

Comment: Thanks for this list. I am a complete Ubuntu Novice. Can you link to the documentation that explains how to stream to RTMP? I'm very overwhelmed with all these foreign commands / documentation.

Comment: How come there are two upvotes, but no explanation how to do this exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You can stream directly to an RMTP address using `ffmpeg` or `avconv` provided you have the necessary authentication (stream key).

An condensed example of using `ffmpeg` to stream to the Twitch.tv RMTP server would be as follows:

```
# stream key. You can set this manually.
STREAM_KEY=$(cat ~/.twitch_key)

# stream url. Note the formats for twitch.tv and justin.tv
# twitch:"rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
# justin:"rtmp://live.justin.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
STREAM_URL="rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"

ffmpeg \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i "pulse" \
-f x11grab -s $(xwininfo -root | awk '/geometry/ {print $2}'i) -r "30" -i :0.0 \
-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s "640x360" -vpre "fast" \
-acodec libmp3lame -threads 6 -qscale 5 -b 64KB \
-f flv -ar 22050 "$STREAM_URL"
```

For more information on how to stream to popular platforms like twitch.tv and justin.tv see [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314144/how-to-stream-on-twitch-tv/370725#370725p).

A gist of an extended version of the above script can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/oseparovic/2db2aaa737cd37e7c068

Answer (score 0):

A good google search finds a bit. Best to do that first. Anyhow its not easy but take a look at this:
http://michaelchinen.com/2011/06/27/justin-tv-streaming-in-linux/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: If you want to improve your answer, you can always edit it (the edit link is under the answer, near the left side).

Comment: That, like all of the other tutorials I've already found through google searches, are obsolete.