# Streaming to Ustream via Desktop

Tags: unity, rtmp, ustream

Is there a software program (preferably professional studio software) which can stream to ustream via RTMP?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org), although it isn't as quite as simple as using FMLE on Windows.

The short answer is that you use a command like

```
ffmpeg <commands to read the input>
   -vcodec libx264 -vpre baseline \
   -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k \
   -threads 0 \
   -f flv "$STREAM_URL"
```

where `$STREAM_URL` is the RTMP URL from Ustream, which will include your channel ID and your user key.

Full details are written in this blog post: 
http://blog.yjl.im/2011/09/broadcasting-using-x11grabr-and-ffmpeg.html

See also this question: [How do I stream to Twitch.tv?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167834/how-do-i-stream-to-twitch-tv)