# Livestreaming with twitch on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

I am trying to find a live streaming tool for Ubuntu 13.04. I am trying to stream it to twitch. I've tryed lots of live streaming tools but they don't work.

So my question is, Is there a live streaming tool for Ubuntu 13.04 with no lag and streams at 720p+?

Twitch: http://www.twitch.tv/ - This is the website I am trying to stream to.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314144/how-to-stream-on-twitch-tv/370725#370725) on the same topic to start you off.

There are a few third party UI based tools that I tried, but most are bloated or don't work properly. Your best bet is likely to use `ffmpeg` or `avconv` and customize the parameters to fit your requirement. Look into these two options to tweak the quality (keep in mind your quality will depend on the quality of your source):

- `-crf` (18-28 is visually "lossless")
- `-qscale:v` (0-10, 10 being best. [Relevant doc](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide))

See the [ffmpeg man page](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) for more details.